# Arnoldi Decomposition Algorithm

Tags: conjugate-gradient, gmres

I try to get into GMRES via Arnoldi-Decomposition. For my understanding, I Implemented the Arnoldi-Decomposition in python.

```
import numpy as np
n = 5
A = np.random.rand(n,n)
v = np.random.rand(n)
M = np.zeros_like(A)
M[:,0] = v
for i in range(1,5):
   M[:,i] = np.matmul(A,M[:,i-1])

d = np.linalg.matrix_rank(M)

V = np.zeros((n,d))
H = np.zeros((d,d))

V[:,0] = v / np.linalg.norm(v)


for j in range(d-1):
    vj = V[:,j]

    Avj = np.matmul(A, vj)

    H[:j+1,j] =  np.matmul(Avj, V[:,:j+1])

    w = Avj - np.matmul(V[:,:j+1] ,H[:j+1,j])    
    H[j+1,j] = np.linalg.norm(w)
    V[:,j+1]  = w/  H[j+1,j]
```

I expected the result to be like $AV_k=H_kV_k$, i.e. to get an arnoldi-decomposition. But when I counter-checked the results, it seems to be off by one iteration:

```
>>np.matmul(A,V)
array([[ 1.74946273,  0.34244799, -0.03368428, -0.52017016, -0.36756412],
       [ 1.01841093,  0.09805327, -0.02055688, -0.82253407, -0.37112225],
       [ 0.81156945,  0.3374741 , -0.11957267,  0.17757239,  0.23021054],
       [ 0.99533205, -0.32793397, -0.12764172,  0.09559959,  0.14891387],
       [ 1.35827635, -0.02004282,  0.24724491, -0.07114606,  0.32279871]])
>>np.matmul(V,H)
array([[ 1.74946273,  0.34244799, -0.03368428, -0.52017016,  0.        ],
       [ 1.01841093,  0.09805327, -0.02055688, -0.82253407,  0.        ],
       [ 0.81156945,  0.3374741 , -0.11957267,  0.17757239,  0.        ],
       [ 0.99533205, -0.32793397, -0.12764172,  0.09559959,  0.        ],
       [ 1.35827635, -0.02004282,  0.24724491, -0.07114606,  0.        ]])
```

So it seems to be that $AV_k = V_{k+1}H_{k+1}$. In my lecture notes, I found this relationship without a proof. So, can somebody show me a proof of it?

Comment: Is it possible to elaborate a bit on your actual question? I mean OK I understand that you implemented Arnoldi decomposition and you found out that $A V_{k} = V_{k+1}H_{k+1}$ instead of $AV_{k} = H_{k}V_{k}$, but I don't see any apparent question here? Please edit it to have an actual question with "?" at the end.

Comment: It's a pretty well known theorem in any book that talks about Arnoldi iteration: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arnoldi_iteration, see references.